# Java Webscraping Data From a Website Hidden Behind User Clicks?

Tags: java, web-scraping

I'm trying to grab the code of https://zotistics.com/ when a certain department is selected, for example selecting "chemistry" on the department dropdown menu brings up a new graph. The problem is that I can't figure out how to extract that HTML code by normal means, as the URL does not change when I select a new department.

Is there any way to retrieve the code of the website *after* a search occurs? I want to be able to gather statistics for GPA based on department/teacher.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the parameters required to select which graph to display are not passed from browser to server by url they are passed by headers and body as formUrlEncoded.
Here are these parameters that affect html page rendering:
`Cookie`
`csrf_token`
`selectDep`

**1 How to get valid value for these parameters and change the display of the page ?**

- `selectDep`: It is easy just the type of graph you want (eg "Chemistry")
  To have the 2 others parameters, you should first do a GET request to https://zotistics.com/ and then you can have `Cookie` and `csrf_token` :
- `Cookie` : To have this,  get it from response headers of that GET request.
- `csrf_token` : To have this, you should go in the response body of that GET request  form ad get the value from the following html `input` tag

```html
<input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="HERE IS THE VALUE you should grab">
```

**2 With theses parameters**

You should issue a POST request to https://zotistics.com/ Setting the `cookie` value and the others params (`csrf_token`, `selectDep`)
by formUrlEncoded. The server will respond with a HTML having an empty container for the canvas `<div id="myChart"></div>` and a Javascript code will fill it. So you need to have a mean to execute the returned HTML + CSS + JS (browser embed in java) to see the HTML rendered and extract the html code of the bar.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few problems. Firstly, because the drop downs are not links, and they do not lead to another page, it is very hard to scrape the chemistry tab or any other tab without physically clicking it first which could be done with java using the Robot() class, however even if you are able to do that the next task is difficult as well. I am assuming you want the data from the graph displayed after you click on a dropdown item, this is difficult because the graphs are created using a `<canvas>` tag which means that the graph is drawn using JavaScript, and also means that the data you are searching for is  likely in a linked .js file (and if so it is unlikely that you will have access to that data), but if not it is in a `<script>` tag which theoretically could be searched through. I do not think it is impossible scraping this website however you should definitely invest time in researching if Zotistics has an API which would simplify this dramatically.